# On the conjecture that $1-\frac 13 + \frac 16 +\frac 1{10} -\frac 1{15}+\cdots = 1\frac 19$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, fractions, triangular-numbers

> > **Conjecture:**
>
> $$1-\frac 13 + \frac 16 +\frac 1{10} -\frac 1{15}+\cdots = 1\frac 19$$ where the pattern of the signs is $+,-,+,+,-,+,+,+,-,\cdots$ and the denominators are the triangular numbers.

Whatever this series converges to (if it does), it converges so slowly. I was on my calculator manually doing this for *hours* (eventually using two at once) and, unless I have erred somewhere,  it seems this approaches $10/9$.

Given the pattern of the signs, I don't think there is a way to write this using summation notation. If I could, then I'd be going straight to Wolfram Alpha. But can this series be shown either convergent or divergent only with by-hand calculation?

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't have another tag spot remaining for [tag:conjectures] and the other tags are perhaps more important.

Comment: The series is absolutely convergent, and so convergent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your series can be written as 
\begin{align}
S&=1-\frac 13 + \frac 16 +\frac 1{10} -\frac 1{15}+\cdots \\
&=\left( 1+\frac 13 + \frac 16 +\frac 1{10} +\frac 1{15}+\cdots\right)-2\left(\frac 13+\frac 1{15}+\cdots\right)
\end{align}
where both series in the expression converge, first one is equal $2$ (sum of reciprocal triangular numbers), second one is $\frac{4}{9}$ (each term is reciprocal of $n(n+3)/2$-th triangular number). Algebraically
$$
S_1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{n(n+1)}=2,S_2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{8}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}=\frac{4}{9},
$$
both series can be computed by telescoping (see also [Find sum of infinite anharmonic(?) series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541224/find-sum-of-infinite-anharmonic-series)). So the result is
$$
S_1-2S_2=2-2\frac{4}{9}=\frac{10}{9}.
$$

Comment: No. It can't have been that simple. I spent half my day manually calculating the series. As buzz light year would put it: "Years of academy training - wasted!"

Comment: On a serious note, though, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: No problem, I like simple :)

Comment: @Sil By the way, there is a fairly general way of dealing with these types of sums you got after the decomposition, see [my question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3538626/631742)

Answer (score 0):

The absolute values of the terms are dominated by 2 / n ^ 2 (2 > 1, 1/2 > 1/3, 2/9 > 1/6, and so forth). 
The summation of 2 / n ^ 2 is pi ^ 2 / 3 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).
So, it is convergent.